# Listing mailboxes a user has access to in Cyrus IMAP?

Tags: imap, cyrus

I wonder if there is a way to list all mailboxes a user has access to via cyradm (or other means). One could run `lam user.%` and parse the output, but I think that sucks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself after poking around with [`IMAP::Admin`](http://search.cpan.org/~eestabroo/IMAP-Admin-1.6.4/Admin.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IMAP::Admin;

$imap = IMAP::Admin->new('Server' => 'localhost',
                           'Login' => 'cyrus',
                           'Password' => 'cyrus',
                           );

my $finduser = "root"; # the user you search for

my @mailboxes = $imap->list("user.%");
foreach my $mailbox (@mailboxes) {
        my %list = $imap->get_acl($mailbox);
        if (defined($list{$finduser})) {
                print $mailbox."\n";
        }
}
```